# Repeating a regex pattern

Tags: regex, sed

First, I don't know if this is actually possible but what I want to do is repeat a regex pattern.
The pattern I'm using is:

```
sed 's/[^-\t]*\t[^-\t]*\t\([^-\t]*\).*/\1/' films.txt
```

An input of

```
250.    7.9    Shutter Island (2010)    110,675
```

Will return:

```
Shutter Island (2010)
```

I'm matching all none tabs, (250.) then tab, then all none tabs (7.9) then tab. Next I backrefrence the film title then matching all remaining chars (110,675).

It works fine, but im learning regex and this looks ugly, the regex [^-\t]*\t is repeated just after itself, is there anyway to repeat this like you can a character like a{2,2}?

I've tried `([^-\t]*\t){2,2}` (and variations) but I'm guessing that is trying to match `[^-\t]*\t\t?`

Also if there is any way to make my above code shorter and cleaner any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be going about this the wrong way. If you're simply wanting to extract the name of the film, and it's release year, then you could try this regex:

```
(?:\t)[\w ()]+(?:\t)
```

As seen in place here:

http://regexr.com?2sd3a

Note that it matches a tab character at the beginning and end of the actual desired string, but doesn't include them in the matching group.

Comment: It might also help to explain what you want the result to be.

Comment: Cheers this works perfectly, thanks for the link, will help with debugging/learning better regex.

Comment: I like how concise this is and see in your link how it *matches*, but how is it used, and with what command, to *extract* the name/date from the line?  I don't see using it with `sed` since it doesn't have a capturing group and replacement. I'll upvote if you add an example of using it in a command to actually produce output that lists the name(s) from a file.

Comment: I'd love to give you a real life example, but I don't know sed. I'm sure this could be rewritten without using non-capturing groups but I'll have to do some research on it.

Comment: Thats a Perl regular expression which `sed` doesn't understand.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
sed 's/\([^\t]*\t\)\{2\}\([^\t]*\).*/\2/' films.txt
```

If your `sed` supports `-r` you can get rid of most of the escaping:

```
sed -r 's/([^\t]*\t){2}([^\t]*).*/\2/' films.txt
```

Change the first `2` to select different fields (0-3).

This will also work:

```
sed 's/[^\t]\+/\n&/3;s/.*\n//;s/\t.*//' films.txt
```

Change the `3` to select different fields (1-4).

Answer (score 6):

To use repeating curly brackets and grouping brackets with `sed` properly, you may have to escape it with backslashes like

`sed 's/\([^-\t]*\t\)\{3\}.*/\1/' films.txt`

Yes, this command will work properly with your example.

If you feel annoyed to, you can choose to put -r option which enables regex extended mode and forget about backslash escapes on brackets.

`sed -r 's/([^-\t]*\t){3}.*/\1/' films.txt`

Found that this is almost the same as Dennis Williamson's answer, but I'm leaving it because it's shorter expression to do the same.

Comment: Thanks. The prepended -r option made the limited repetition possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat things by putting them in parenthesis, like this:

```
([^-\t]*\t){2,2}
```

And the full pattern to match the title would be this:

```
([^-\t]*\t){2,2}([^-\t]+).*
```

You said you tried it.  I'm not sure what is different, but the above worked for me on your sample data.

Comment: I was trying things out myself, and just used what you wrote here and it's not working for me either. I tried with plain parens as you typed it `( ... )` (not expecting it to work) and escaped parens `\\( ... \\)`, also escaping the `\+` ... my `sed --version` says `GNU sed version 4.1.5` and it's on RedHat Enterprise 5.1 [oh look, the backslash didn't show in the comment until I doubled it `\\\(`]

Comment: You need to either use `sed -r` or escape both the parens *and* braces in order for this to work in sed.

Answer (score 2):

why are you doing things the hard way??

```
$ awk '{$1=$2=$NF=""}1' file
  Shutter Island (2010)
```

Comment: Presuming the file is tab delimited: awk -F"|" '{print $3,$4}' filename

Answer (score 1):

If this is a tab separated file with a regular format I'd use `cut` instead of `sed`

`cut -d'   ' -f3 films.txt`

Note there's a single *tab* between the quotes after the `-d` which can be typed at the shell prompt by typing ctrl+v first, i.e. `ctrl+v ctrl+i`

Comment: there are spaces between movie names.

Comment: @ghostdog : according to the OPs regex there are tabs, not spaces.